# How to apply Style Frame on individual cells using apply_style_by_indexes()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, styleframe

is there a way to apply StyleFrame on individual cells rather than using some conditional statements to style the entire row.

Comment: Kindly refer to [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html#Precision).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it is not straightforward.

You can abuse the fact that `apply_style_by_indexes` accepts a `cols_to_style` argument (see the [docs](https://styleframe.readthedocs.io/en/latest/styleframe.html?highlight=apply_style_by_indexes#styleframe.StyleFrame.apply_style_by_indexes)), and the fact that you can pass an index directly:

```
sf = StyleFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3], 'b': [4, 5, 6], 'c': [7, 8, 9]})
sf.apply_style_by_indexes(sf.index[1], Styler(bg_color='yellow'), cols_to_style='b')
```

This will only style the cell that contains `5` because it is the "intersection" of `sf.index[1]` and the `b` column.